# Developing: Where to start?

Tags: python, development, javascript

I'm interested in getting into the technicalities of the OS, perhaps by doing some developing but mainly just understanding how everything works on Ubuntu!

I've been using it for about 6 months and I absolutely love it and the whole community, I know some basic Python and Javascript (I've been taking the Codecademy courses) but I really don't know where to start.

Any ideas will be welcomed (books, websites or even just something that I should look into).

Thanks in advance!

Jo

Comment: If you're interested about Ubuntu(the OS) development itself, check this [UbuntuDevelopers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment) wiki page. Python is good, but how's your C/C++ skills?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Ubuntu developers community could help you :

http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/developers/

Emman